# Менять свойство transform: rotate через JS

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, css-animation

Изначальная задача у меня это менять по кругу цветные квадраты. Думаю это сделать меняя свойство transform: rotate у большого квадрата.

```css
.egg {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.egg-item {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.egg-item-1 {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.egg-item-2 {
    background-color: red;
}

.egg-item-3 {
    background-color: green;
}

.egg-item-4 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="egg">
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-1"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-2"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-3"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-4"></div>
</div>
```

Сначала попробовал сделать через бесконечную анимацию css. Но так не получается, т.к. квадрат постоянно возвращается в положение from.

```
    @keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
```

И вот думаю как это решить с помощью JS. По сути мне нужно написать функцию которая берёт значение rotate(0deg) и к нему прибавлять + 90 deg. Но как получить значение не могу разобраться. Подскажите как получать это значение?

Или можно обойтись без js вообще?

Comment: что значит "меня по кругу цветные квадраты" и какое отношение к этому имеет `rotate`?

Comment: @ThisMan менять расположение квадратов по часовой стрелке. Через rotate например этого можно добиться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так можно при помощи js:

```js
document.querySelector('.egg').onclick = function () {
  this.style.transform = `rotate(${this.d = (this.d | 0) + 90}deg)`;
}
```

```css
.egg {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: auto; 
  transition: 300ms;
}
.egg-item { width: 20px; height: 20px;}
.egg-item-1 {background-color: rebeccapurple;}
.egg-item-2 {background-color: red;}
.egg-item-3 {background-color: green;}
.egg-item-4 {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
кликните на квадрат
<div class="egg">
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-1"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-2"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-3"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-4"></div>
</div>
```

если анимация не нужна уберите  transition: 300ms;

---

Если прямо очень хочется именно получать значение из стиля, то код будет слегка посложнее

```js
document.querySelector('.egg').onclick = function () {
  var m = window.getComputedStyle(this).transform.split('(').pop().split(',');
  var a = 180/Math.PI * Math.atan2(m[1], m[0]) + 90;
  this.style.transform = `rotate(${a}deg)`;
}
```

```css
.egg {
  width: 40px; height: 40px;
  display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: auto; 
  transform: rotate(11deg);
}
.egg-item { width: 20px; height: 20px;}
.egg-item-1 {background-color: rebeccapurple;}
.egg-item-2 {background-color: red;}
.egg-item-3 {background-color: green;}
.egg-item-4 {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
кликните на квадрат
<div class="egg">
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-1"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-2"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-3"></div>
    <div class="egg-item egg-item-4"></div>
</div>
```

тут приходится получать значения угла из матрицы трансформации, которую возвращает 
[`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)